# How to subset a data.frame if the column contains NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

R (version 3.3.3) is giving me some unexpected behavior when subsetting a data frame on a condition based on a character column. Here is an example:

```
foo <- data.frame(bar = c('a',NA,'b','a'),
                  baz = 1:4,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`foo` looks like this:

```
   bar baz
1    a   1
2 <NA>   2
3    b   3
4    a   4
```

I want to get all rows of this data frame where `bar != "a"`, so I call:

```
foo[foo$bar != 'a', ]
```

This returns:

```
    bar baz
NA <NA>  NA
3     b   3
```

I do not understand why the first entry in the second column is `NA` and not `2`. Please help me explain this strange behavior.

Comment: Use `which`: `foo[which(foo$bar != 'a'), ]`.

Comment: @nicola unfortunately that does not give the desired behavior either, it returns only row 3 (doesn't return the row where `bar` is `NA`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm trying to understand the behaviour, the right/better way to do character filter in R is to use `%in%` operator.

```
foo <- data.frame(bar = c('a',NA,'b','a'),
                  baz = 1:4,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

foo[!(foo$bar %in% 'a'), ]
```

Output:

```
> foo[!(foo$bar %in% 'a'), ]
   bar baz
2 <NA>   2
3    b   3
```

Update:

The behaviour isn't because of character filter. It's actually because `NA` is used to index the dataframe.

```
> foo[c(F,NA,T,F),]
    bar baz
NA <NA>  NA
3     b   3
```

Passing `NA` as index value replaces any value in that position with just `NA`

```
> foo[NA,]
      bar baz
NA   <NA>  NA
NA.1 <NA>  NA
NA.2 <NA>  NA
NA.3 <NA>  NA
> foo[c(T,NA),]
      bar baz
1       a   1
NA   <NA>  NA
3       b   3
NA.1 <NA>  NA
```